# Applications icon changes when Matplotlib graph shows up and never revert - macOS only

Tags: macos, matplotlib, tkinter

I am pretty new to python, tkinter and matplotlib.

I need to show a graph from a simple tkinter app and everything works as expected.

The problem is that when the graph shows up, the icon's app in the docker changes to this:

[image]

Closing the graph's window the icon doesn't revert to the original one and this is quite annoying.

I have tried some proposed solutions I have found on StackOverflow but apparently nothing works. Likely it's me.

My environment:

- macos: 14.1.1 (Sonoma)
- Python: 3.12 (installed from downloaded package)
- PyCharm: 2023.2.5

I am experiencing the same behavior even with older versions of python but the same code works fine on Windows.

This is my test code (excerpt to proof the issue).

```
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

root = Tk()


def show_graph():
    print("Graph")
    a = [90.2, 123.8, 110.2, 108.1, 115.0]
    b = [100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
    target = [98, 98, 98, 98, 98]
    weeks = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

    plt.Figure()
    figure1 = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 2), dpi=200)
    ax = figure1.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_xticks(list(range(1, 24)))

    plt.plot(weeks, a, '--.', label="A")
    plt.plot(b, 'r--', label="B")
    plt.plot(target, 'g--', label="C")
    plt.legend()
    plt.xlabel('Week')
    plt.ylabel('A', labelpad=1)
    plt.grid(True, which="both", ls="-")

    figure1.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

    root.title("Matplotlib Icon Issue")
    root.geometry('500x500')

    frame = Frame(root)
    frame.pack()

    Label(frame, text="label").grid(row=0, column=0)
    Button(frame, text="Graph", command=show_graph).grid(row=1, column=0)

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update

The way `matplotlib` sets icon depends on the backend.

You are setting `TkAgg` backend here

```
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
```

which creates a `Tkinter` window behind the scenes and sets the icon forcefully [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/0a4efbeed0c784dee4a44ab4da8cc02c647510fe/lib/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py#L501C16-L501C16). This doesn't look customizable/optional. I don't have access to Windows machine, so not sure why it is working differently in there.

However, my original reply suggests (with one missing part) to not use dynamic backend for `matplotlib`, instead embed plots directly to the `Tkinter` window you own and control. Theoretically, this wouldn't allow `matplotlib` to change icon (I admit that I didn't test my suggested code in the original reply).

One thing I missed in the original answer is that, even if you don't call `figure.show()` method, `matplotlib` triggers backend renderer whenever you create the `Figure`. Therefore, it still updates the icon.

As a fix to my original solution, if you set `matplotlib` backend to one of non-dynamic backends, it won't be able to set the icon (also wouldn't allow you to use `.show` method).

e.g. (tested in MacOS 12.7, Python 3.12).

```
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

### Original Answer

You are using matplotlib's window manager when showing the graph and not using Tkinter at all, therefore this is expected.

Since you are already using Tkinter window manager, then you shouldn't be using `.show` method of figure, instead you can embed figure to Tkinter Canvas.

Example from https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html

```
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

root = Tk()


def show_graph():
    ...
    figure1 = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 2), dpi=200)
    ...
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure1, master=root)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)
```

Comment: This code allow to show the graph without opening a new window (actually useful in some cases) but DOESN'T solve the main issue. As soon as the graph shows up, the application icon changes and doesn't revert even if the widget containing the graph is destroyed.

Comment: Updated, now it SOLVES the main issue.